# How to make a Row widget a Flexible widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

Dart file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HqM_nxCiCCmx-swLInrSQfwwAmiXRVK3/view?usp=sharing

I have been getting this message: Right Overflowed by 200 pixels
You can see the code and please help to solve it and make the ow widget a flexible one without changing the alignment
[see the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7sGe.png)

I have tried SingleChildScrollView, Wrap but all of them change the alignment to center.

Code:

```
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.mail),
                          Text(
                            " " + usersData[index]['email'],
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
```

Comment: "You can see the code and please help to solve it", nobody can see the code because you have not shared it.

Comment: Could you post your detail of your code? so we can help

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HqM_nxCiCCmx-swLInrSQfwwAmiXRVK3/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

try to change your Row Widget into Column.

If your Row Widget is like this:

```
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
        new Text("..."),
    ]
)
```

Change it to :

```
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, // for the horizontal alignment
    children: <Widget>[
        new Text("..."),
    ]
)
```

Comment: Did you see the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7sGe.png
I have inserted the the row inside a column which is inside a Card
So how can i make the card/row horizontally scroll able

Comment: Just put anything you want to make it become horizontally scrollable into ListView with scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,

Comment: I just used 'Expanded(child: Text())' and this worked for me